# test for process return status returns unexpected results on ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, return

Here's a piece of shell script code that I am executing on an ubuntu machine:

```
myProcess
ret="$?"
if [  "${ret}" == "0" ]
then
   echo good
else
   echo bad "${ret}"
fi
```

So the logic is pretty simple: if `myProcess` returns a non-zero exit status, it's bad, otherwise good. I tested this piece of code by isolating it into a separate script and running it from command line. When `myProcess` returned 0, I got `good` as expected.

However, when I run it in production, I get `bad 0`. So even though the return code seems to be 0, the `if` test seems to return `false`. What's going on here?

Comment: what is your "shebang" line? `#!/bin/bash` or #!/bin/sh` ? (Can't see right now why it would matter, but as you're not showing the whole script there may be an incompatibility between executing with bash VS the original Bourne Shell.) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: it's `#!/bin/sh`. Also, in case it matters, in production this script gets executed as a cron job.

Comment: I don't think bourne shell supports `==`.. Depending on your OS, is your `#!/bin/sh` really Bash, or Bourne. First try just `=` and if that doesn't resolve the problem then go for debugging the actual value of `ret` with `"X${ret}X" = X0X"`, `echo bad X${ret}X`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was in the use of too many quotes possibly in combination with `==`. The following modified code seems to be working fine:

```
myProcess
ret=$?
if [  ${ret} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo good
else
    echo bad "${ret}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to do it (no need to treat `$?` and creating a copy of the variable):

```
if myProcess; then
   echo "good"
else
   echo "bad" >&2
fi
```

If `myProcess` is coded properly, that should works. If not, paste the exact output/errors in your original post.

This short and concise way is named *boolean logic*

Comment: But what's wrong with my code above? I need to capture the return code since in the "bad" case, I need to pass it as one of the parameters to a process that generates a special alert for this case.